# Estimating the double integral $\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-y} x^n(1-x)^ny^n(1-y)^n dx dy$ with $ x,y\in (0,1)$.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I saw a problem similar to this: it was needed to find a estimation for,
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \int_0^{1} x^n(1-x)^ny^n(1-y)^n dx dy 
\end{align}
with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\geq 1$. The resolution goes: define $f(x,y) = x(1-x)y(1-y)$ with $ x,y\in (0,1)$. The maximum of $f$ occurs at $f(1/2,1/2) = 1/16$, therefore,
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \int_0^{1} x^n(1-x)^ny^n(1-y)^n dx dy < (1/16)^n
\end{align}

I wonder if we can do something similar to estimate:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-y} x^n(1-x)^ny^n(1-y)^n dx dy
\end{align}
with $ x,y\in (0,1)$ and $1\leq n \in \mathbb{Z}$, without actually evaluating the integral. I'm not even sure if this makes sense. The integral above is a real number depending on $n$, I want to estimate this value, bound the integral, like the problem before. Also, the integrals are improper ones.

Comment: For the first problem, we can write the integral as the product of two beta integrals, with the restriction $n>-1$.

Comment: For the first integral, the region of integration is the square $\square = [0,1]\times[0,1]$. For the second integral, we are integrating over the triangle $\{(x,y)|0\le x,\:0\le y,\: x+y=1\}$, which is the lower triangle in the square $\square$ sliced by one of its diagonals (lower part of $\diagdown \!\!\!\!\! \square$) . Since the integrand function is symmetric under the transformation $(x\mapsto 1-x, y\mapsto 1-y)$, the second integral is always exactly half of the first one (so you can in particular take the bound $(1/16)^n /2$, or half of any bound you obtained for the first integral).